# Bluebird: How to bind a promise so that I can customize behavior in .catch, and then allow error to continue cascading?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

**Note- see the update below**

I want have a flow with a dependency between the first task to the execution between the other secondary tasks, but the other secondary tasks can all be run concurrently.
I want to write a clean flow which will make it easy to handle errors, and I've tried several variations but can't get it right.

Here's what I will be working with, regardless of the pattern I compose it:

```
var primaryAsyncTask  = {...}; //single 'task' which has an execution function
var secondaryAsyncTasks = [{...}]; //array of tasks with same format as above
function promisifyTask(task){ .... }; //returns a promise which executes the task and appends the resolve/reject functions as the last arguments to the task execution function
```

Now here's the two options I currently tried:

1. In promisifyTask, I wrap the rejection handler and bind it to the task, so that I can customize the failure info and then check it upon final catch. In other words, the flow looks like this:

.

```
function taskRejecter(reject, reason) {
    //do something to save info from reason onto this = task
    reject();
}

function promisifyTask(task) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var rejecter = taskRejecter.bind(task, reject);
        task.execute.apply(null, task.args.concat([resolve, rejecter]));
    });
}
//and then when executing:
promisifyTask(primaryAsyncTask)
    .then(function () {
        return Promise.settle(secondaryAsyncTasks.map(function (task) {
            return promisifyTask(task);
        }));
    })
    .then(function onSuccess() {...
    })
    .catch(function onFail() {
        //map all the info from the failed tasks (primary/secondary) to the info saved in it by the taskRejecter.
    });
```

The advantage here is that if the primary task fails, it doesn't execute the secondary tasks and reaches the onFail in the catch... but if it succeeds, it executes them and will reach the onFail only if one of them fails (which is also desired behavior).

2. Alternatively, which looks much nicer internally, is to bind the promise and catch it, instead of wrapping the rejection handler, and then I can handle everything in a single 'taskFailCatcher' function, so it would look like this:

   ```
   function onTaskFail(reason){
       //do something to save info from reason onto this = task, since it was bound before the catch
   }

   function promisifyTask(task){
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
           task.execute.apply(null, task.args.concat([resolve, reject]));
       });
   }
   function promisifyTaskAndCatch(task){
       return promisifyTask(task).bind(task).catch(onTaskFail)
   }
   //and then when executing:
   promisifyTask(primaryAsyncTask)
               .then(function (){
                      return Promise.settle(secondaryAsyncTasks.map(function (task) {
                           return promisifyTaskAndCatch(task);
                      }));
                })
               .then(function onSuccess(){...})
               .catch(function onFail(){...})
   ```

I like the .bind.catch, but the problem here is twofold:

1. The flow is not consistent. I don't want to execute the secondary tasks when the primary fails, so I use promisifyTask for the primary (so that it is not caught, and reaches the catch at the end), but I promisifyTaskAndCatch inside the .settle, so that I can easily bind and edit the failure info for the task directly after the rejection.
2. The .catch here is reached only after the primary fails. Now that I catch all the secondary tasks, the .settle will always receive fulfilled promises, so I reach onSuccess even if a secondary task fails.

How can I edit this flow so that I make use of the best of both worlds (.bind.catch for error handling, with a consistent and clear flow)?

**-----------------UPDATE------------------**

I *almost* figured this out. I changed it by removing promisifyTaskAndCatch and changing promisifyTask to be:

```
function promisifyTask(task) {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        task.execute.apply(null, task.args.concat([resolve, reject]));
    });
    promise.bind(task).catch(onTaskFail);
    return promise;
}
```

Now the syntax is consistent and the error cascades through, and I also get my error reporting.

The only problem is now that I don't have a guarantee that the internal catch for the task will happen before the external final catch (with the onFail at the end of the chain), since this is async.

Is there a way to return the caught promise, but still have it fail? can I do this without just rethrowing an error inside of .catch ?

Comment: I would suggest to name your function `runTask`. "Promisification" is a different thing.

Comment: You're right - the function promisifyTask is actually like 'promisifiedTask'. Promisification would return the promisifyTask without running it...

Comment: Uh, something else: Doesn't `Promise.settle` return an always resolved promise, so that your global `onFail` handler will never see the reasons from the rejected secondary tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only problem is now that I don't have a guarantee that the internal catch for the task will happen before the external final catch (with the onFail at the end of the chain), since this is async

Actually you do have, since the `.catch(onTaskFail)` is invoked first the `onTaskFail` would be executed before the final one. But you are right, if the final catch depends on things that `onTaskFail` does then it would be much cleaner to actually return a promise for that result.

> Is there a way to return the caught promise, but still have it fail?

I think re-`throw`ing the `reason` would be the best.

Or you even don't have them fail, and use [`Promise.all`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise) and inspect the task objects about their results instead of using [`Promise.settle`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#settle---promise) and its `PromiseInspection` values. As you say the reason is saved on the tasks, the most consistent flow would be to return the task objects:

```
function onTaskFail(reason){
    this.error = reason; // or so
    return this;
}
runTask(primaryAsyncTask).then(function(primResult) {
    return Promise.all(secondaryAsyncTasks.map(function (task) {
        return runTask(task).bind(task).catch(onTaskFail);
    }));
}).then(function(taskResults) {
    // test for errors in the secondary results
    // and throw them if you want the global onFail
    // else do onSuccess()
}).catch(onFail);
```

> can I do this without just rethrowing an error inside of .catch ?

Yes, you can also `return` a rejected promise. That might be a `Promise.reject(reason)`, but simpler might be to `return promise` that is already there (though not currently in scope of `onTaskFail`). The [`.return()` helper method](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#returndynamic-value---promise) could be used here though:

```
…
    return promise.bind(task).catch(onTaskFail).return(promise);
```

Comment: very interesting - the returning of the task from within the catch. I like it. 
Regarding the Promise.all - it will reject immediately if any of them fail, but I want to wait for all of them to finish, which is why I'm using settle... though it seems like it will always return a fulfilled promise.

Maybe I can do:
runTask().then(runAlllTasks //returns promise.settle).then(function(reasons){return Promise.all(reasons)}).then(onSuccess).catch(onFail)

Comment: But as you `.catch()` all errors, none of them will fail…

Comment: if I use Promise.all on the settled results, if anything fails, it will always reach the catch, which is nice. I'll post it as an update

Comment: Really, that works? Sounds more like a hack to me, I don't see why `Promise.all` should get rejected by getting a `PromiseInspection` object

Comment: I don't know if it's intended, but it works logically if you follow the bluebird source. See: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/promise_array.js

Follow the init (this is Promise.all) - a promiseInspection does not get cast into a promise, and eventually enters PromiseArray$_settlePromiseAt in the direct scan of the values, where it asks value.isFulfilled() and value.isRejected() which PromiseInspection objects have. It almost looks intentional, because it seems the only way to even reach that far in the check is if the cast returns the original PromiseInspection

Comment: I will ask this in bluebird's github

Comment: looks like I was using an older version of bluebird when testing this, because on the current version, it does not work. It's fulfilled.